# Check that a row (text) exists on a table in web by selenium (with Python)

Tags: python, selenium, html-table

[image]

I need to check that (the line what is being bordered) is appeared on web.
I used xpath //td[6] to select this row but I don't know how to check whether text "`1/06/2021 3:00PM 5551110050 933 and so on`" is exist on this page.

I tried using `//td[contains(text(),'5551110050')]` but only select 1 elements, I need to concatenate many text to check this row

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` which will identify the row based on string.

> //tr[contains(.,'1/6/2021 3:00PM') and contains(.,'5551110050') and contains(.,'933')]

Check the length count if it more than 0 then Item Found else not

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(.,'1/6/2021 3:00PM') and contains(.,'5551110050') and contains(.,'933')]")):
    print("WebElement exists")
else:
    print("WebElement was not detected")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **.text of your WebElement** to check what you want. For example :

```
for td in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/td"):
    if '5551110050' in td.text:
        print('OK')
```

I hope it'll work on your side !

Comment: Thanks but not my mind, I need a str "1/6/2021 3:00PM " and "5551110050" and "933" all match in 1 row. I need to check they all appear in a row or not.

Comment: Ok I see do you have any example of the HTML code containing all those informations ?